# Can we have a conditionally convergent alternating series that fails the alternating series test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that if a series fails the alternating series test (i.e. at least one of the 3 conditions are not met), it doesn't necessarily imply divergence. For example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/836801/1195032) question links some absolutely convergent alternating series that fail the alternating series test. However, can we have a conditionally convergent alternating series that fails the alternating series test?

In other words, can we have a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ that satisfies the following criteria:

- the series is alternating
- the series converges
- $\{|a_n|\}$ is not decreasing
- $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ diverges

Comment: Perhaps, you want $(|a_n|)$ to be not even eventually decreasing. An example where $|a_2|>|a_1|$ is very easy to consruct.

Comment: What about $a_n = (-1)^n/n + 1/n^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexamples can be constructed as $\sum(b_n + c_n)$ where $\sum b_n$ is conditionally convergent and alternating, and $\sum c_n$ is absolutely convergent and chosen such that $\sum(b_n + c_n)$ is still alternating, but $(|b_n+c_n|)$ is not decreasing.

A concrete example is
$$
 a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \frac{1}{2n^2} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \left( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right) \, .
$$
$\sum a_n$ is alternating, and convergent as the sum of two convergent series. $\sum a_n$ is not absolutely convergent because that would imply that
$$
 \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = \sum \left( a_n - \frac{1}{2n^2}\right)
$$
is absolutely convergent. Also
$$
 |a_n| \ge \frac 1 n \cdot \frac 12
$$
shows that $\sum a_n$ is not absolutely convergent.

Remains to show that $(|a_n|)$ is not decreasing: For odd $n$ is
$$
 |a_{n+1}| - |a_n| = \left(\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)^2}\right) -\left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2}\right)
= \frac{1}{2n^2(n+1)^2} > 0 \, .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Intertwin the alternating harmonic series and its double:
$$\color{red}{\frac11,-\frac12,}\color{blue}{\frac21,-\frac22,}\color{red}{\frac13,-\frac14,}\color{blue}{\frac23,-\frac24,}\color{red}{\frac15,-\frac16,}\color{blue}{\frac25,-\frac26,}$$$$\dots,\color{red}{\frac1{2n-1},-\frac1{2n},}\color{blue}{\frac2{2n-1},-\frac2{2n},}\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

$[(\frac  1 3-\frac  1 4)+(1-\frac   12)]+[(\frac  1 7-\frac  1 8)+(\frac  1 5-\frac  1 6)]+\cdots$ where I pick two terms at a time from $\sum \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ and switch these two by two.

$(.),[.]$ are used only for clarity and you should take individual terms ignoring all brackets.